# Multiple processes read/write files. What API to use?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, fork, mmap

I have this situation when I need to spawn worker processes. On one side, worker processes should read evenly split parts of a file and pass data to socket connection. Other side should read that data and write it in parallel. I plan to split source file into parts beforehand so that each process gets only one part of a file to read from or write to.

So I'm already using sockets with read/write. From that, I think, it is better for me to continue to use this simple API. But I can not find any means of setting file pointer when using file descriptors. I need that obviously, when reading from file that is divided to read/write parts.

I've heard that mmap can help me somehow. But to my understanding mmap needs much RAM and my app will run multiple mentioned transfers. The app is also quite limited in CPU usage.
 The question is, what API should I use?

**EDIT** I be on Linux. Filesystem is ext4.

Comment: It is operating system specific, and it could be file system specific

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Did an edit.

Comment: When you wrote "setting file pointer" did you mean "setting file position"? If so, you can use `lseek` or `llseek`. Or if you meant "setting a `FILE *`" you can use `fdopen`.

Comment: How do the worker processes know what part of what file to read and provide to a socket connection? If the other end of the socket connection provides that info, then a small pool of threads (pool size depending on the storage medium used) can handle any number of socket clients. This is a common, solved problem; file servers do exactly this at their core.

Comment: @IanAbbott I meant file descriptor. lseek made my day. How could had i miss it?

Comment: @NominalAnimal The other end of socket connection provides info about which file to read. The app forks, passes some information to exec. The new process will know the file, which part of it to read/send over socket.

Comment: You can also use [`pread()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html). It is particularly useful in the case where one process provides data read from a single file or small number of files to many socket clients, since only one descriptor per file is needed (as opposed to one descriptor per client). It essentially combines the seek and the read, except that the file position is unchanged (even for simultaneous access using the same file descriptor).

Comment: @NominalAnimal Wow, never heard of pread(). I will definitely give it a try. BTW what you think of mmap() approach?

Comment: @ЯрославМашко: `mmap()` approach is excellent if the clients request smallish chunks at random addresses; it can outperform `read()`/`pread()` in some cases, as you can simply send the data directly from the mapping, without a buffer in between. The kernel is also surprisingly good at managing which pages of the mapping to keep in RAM. For linear accesses, say in 16k or larger chunks, `read()`/`pread()` is more efficient, in my experience.

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable information.